# Can i get the execution trace for a test case for a java program?

Tags: java, trace, execution

I want to run a java program with some test input values and when the execution ends I want to know the complete execution trace, for each conditional statement - what path was followed.
Is there anything that can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just use the [debugging API](http://docs.rinet.ru/JaTricks/ch26.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

You can transparently intercept and log code execution using this. I'm not sure you can intercept every (say) `if()` statement, but you can certainly intercept method calls etc., and you should hopefully then be able to derive the execution flow from there.